# css media type print using background-color in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using the `background-color` property in CSS **media type print**.

The problem is that Google Chrome does not show `background-color` or `background-image` in print preview.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 38):

Chrome supports control of background colour / image printing via CSS. You can set the following CSS property on elements whose background should be printed:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Normally of course, this is determined by browser settings - but Chrome allows web designers to determine how backgrounds are printed on a per-element basis...

Notes:

- Requires Chrome 17 or higher.
- The background of the body tag is not printed.

Thanks to Cron’s Web Tech Blog, where I first spotted it:-

http://blog.crondesign.com/2011/11/print-css-backgrounds-in-google-chrome.html

Also, this leads to some background (no pun intended!) info regarding the feature:-

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107763

Hope this helps...

Comment: Nice find. Also note that there is currently a bug with it and CSS gradients.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any more... at least as of Chrome 22.0.1229.79.

Comment: Have just tested (with Chrome 25.0.1364.97) and it still works fine for me. One thing to look out for though is whether the css is applied to 'screen' media only... (more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Answer (score 14):

I tried for hours using the ideas suggested but none worked. I needed to use `!important`

Somehow chrome must be deferring to a different background-color statement.

`background-color:red !important`

Comment: This was the only solution that worked in Chrome for me. -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; did NOT work in Chrome for some reason.

Comment: yup, same for me. Perhaps web-kit custom css only worked in previous versions of Chrome but on latest which is 37, it doesnt

Comment: I think this post should get some attention. So far this is the only solution that is working. and it makes me hate print support. because i hate using !important

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is not with your code, but with Chrome: there is no option to print background (images or colors) : see http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=17a4ac343580c8d3&hl=en

With Firefox, the background images are not printed by default, but it can be activated in "Print... -> Page setup"

Comment: Good find. Earlier I was going bananas all over the web.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the developer tools in chrome to check which css rules applied in your DOM element. That will help you debug and fix the issue.