# Can I force text to print as white?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have some text which is displayed over an image or some other printable colours. Is it possible to force this text to white when printing? The default behaviour is to force white to black or grey in most browsers. This clearly makes sense when you are printing text in containers with background colours/images which are removed, but doesn't make sense to force the text in the case where you are overlaying text on images.

I should probably mention that I am quite aware of the print stylesheet, it just so happens that regardless of setting the font colour, in IE/chrome/firefox, the font does not appear white regardless. It ends up black or grey depending on the browser. Please show an example of white text over an image if you think it's actually possible.

To illustrate see:

http://jsfiddle.net/NSwYE/

I personally don't think it's possible due to the way printing works. It's pretty annoying none-the-less.

Comment: You want white text to print on top of the image? Or are you trying to make the text 'invisible'?

Comment: I want to print the text on top of the image. I want the white text to remain white, i.e. causing the printer to not print any colour where those overlaying letters are, assuming the paper is white.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### This is not entirely in control of the web page author.

For example, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3HFm/3/) will print (at least it did for me on a Dell 1720 Laser Printer) white text on any of the three black backgrounds in

### IE9

***if*** the ***user*** has checked the box found next to:

> Tools -> Print -> Page Setup -> "Print Background Colors and Images"

If that box is unchecked, then it will not print the black at all on the first two, but will on the last (since it is an `img` tag), but it prints the text as a grey, even over the `img` tag. Thus, it seems that the setting for "Print Background Colors and Images" affects how the browser interprets the text, and will allow a true white (knock-out effect) if checked, but not if unchecked.

### Firefox

Checkbox found here (which seems to work):

> File -> Page Setup -> "Print Background (colors & images)"

### For Chrome? Web Page Author Controlled?

I have not yet verified whether the information from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768717/css-media-type-print-using-background-color-in-chrome) will do it or not (it does not work for me on [my next fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3HFm/4/), but it may be because it is in an iframe). For elements that should print in Chrome, try setting:

```css
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Comment: -webkit-print-color-adjust worked for me in chrome. I really didn't know that a browser allowed author-controlled printing hints. It's about time all browsers exposed this level of control. There's no reason why content authors shouldn't be allowed to do this.

Comment: @MattEsch--It's a give and take. I am not sure that Chrome allows the user any control (which is also bad); also, the fact that Chrome requires this to be set to get it to print at all seems a bit of a pain, but at least it does allow the author to specify which images to print, allowing all others not to (it is not all or nothing).

Comment: @ScottS you are the winner again

Comment: The option on latest firefox has been changed. On printing dialogue, we have to click the options tab and then choose "Print Background Colors"

Comment: I had to add an !important attribute to the css for it to print correctly, eg "color: white !important"

Answer (score 12):

Marked answer is wrong. **You can control text color in every browser!** You just need to output text in svg. Browsers don't change color in svg. Here's an example:

```
<svg height="40" width="200">
   <text font-size="28px" y="25" x="30" fill="#ffffff" >
   Some text
   </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: My constraint in this case was to not use svg as I was writing a simple canvas implementation based on DOM nodes (div elements) targeting ie8, which doesn't support svg.

Comment: It doesn't work for firefox. I have not tested on other browsers.

Comment: Thanks Jehy. Your answer  worked well in most of the browsers(IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) after I try lot of other solutions. :)

Answer (score 11):

`print.css` will help you, Eric meyer have a [post](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html) about it.

For example [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) using this style on [his css](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/style.css):

```
@media print {
  * { background: transparent !important; color: black !important; box-shadow:none !important; text-shadow: none !important; } /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
  a, a:visited { text-decoration: underline; }
  a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
  abbr[title]:after { content: " (" attr(title) ")"; }
  .ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; } /* Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links */
  pre, blockquote { border: 1px solid #999; page-break-inside: avoid; }
  thead { display: table-header-group; } /* h5bp.com/t */
  tr, img { page-break-inside: avoid; }
  img { max-width: 100% !important; }
  @page { margin: 0.5cm; }
  p, h2, h3 { orphans: 3; widows: 3; }
  h2, h3 { page-break-after: avoid; }
}
```

**Update:**

With your example html:

```
<img src="http://www.clipart.dk.co.uk/DKImages/Halloween/image_halloween002.jpg" alt="black cat">
<div id="sometext">Cat</div>
```

and my css:

```
#sometext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    left: 220px;
    color: #FFF; 
}

@media only print {

#sometext {
    color: #FFF !important;
    /* actually trick with white text-shadow not work ( */
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF !important;
}

}
```

​
I get [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/NSwYE/5/embedded/result/). Is this an acceptable solution?

[image]
    ​

Comment: How does this relate to printing white text over an image?

Comment: @this example can help you, because it works. For more help, can you provide some jsFiddle demo?

Comment: @MattEsch `#white` it doesn't work, because you mix `#rgb` syntax and color name syntax

Comment: By default the text in chrome is grey, so you can actually read it. Try it out in Firefox, or IE (6+)

Answer (score 7):

**Solution:**

```
    @media print {
      h1 {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
      }

      @media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        h1 {
          color: #fff;
          -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The example http://jsfiddle.net/NSwYE/ prints white text on top of the cat for me. But I'm using Firefox 3.6 and a Brother laser printer.

**The behaviour of printers is entirely dependent on the printer driver and the application.** My printer will print the example correctly using Firefox. It will print grey-scale text from Microsoft Publisher correctly. It will not print grey-scale text in Microsoft Word: text is always black.

Comment: For me text color is still gray in chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Text color */
.element
{
   color:transparent; 
   text-shadow:0 0 0 #fff; 
}

/* Background color */
.element
{
   box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px #000 inset; 
}
```

In Internet Explorer, you need to enable background printing. Tested in Chrome 70, Firefox 60 (with disabled background printing also works) and IE11.

It doesn't need to calculate SVG width because SVG is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, if you use a print specific stylesheet that styles it as such.

e.g.

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
```

Comment: I've read suggestions for this but have not yet seen it working.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit overkill, but if this is something you need repeatedly, you might consider generating the content using either canvas or SVG (Raphael.js will provide IE support). Both canvas and SVG/VML elements will print with exact colours in major browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an !important attribute to the css for it to print correctly, eg "color: white !important"