# How to print white text with black background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I am trying to print white text with black background image, but it is working only when we enable "Print Background (Colors & Image). Is there any way to enable this through jquery or other work around to fix this problem. Here is my sample code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    var print = $('.printButton');
    print.bind('mousedown', function () {
             $('.FirstName').attr("style", "background: transparent !important;color:#FFEFD5;-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;");
              window.print();
             });
         });
</script>

<div >
    <div >
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgIO" ImageUrl="/css/Images/Img-Black.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="FirstName">Hello</div>
</div>

<div>
   <div class="printButton">
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2"  />
   </div>
</div>


.FirstName {
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 72px;  
}
.printButton {
    margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
    float: right;
    font-family: Arial;
    direction: ltr;
}
```

I verified this link [Can I force text to print as white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684392/can-i-force-text-to-print-as-white) already, but I am unable to find the solution.

Can anyone help me to sort this issue.

Many Thanks
Anna

Comment: im not sure if i understand your question but what's wrong with setting `color: white; background-color: black;` in css ?

Comment: @brendan Thanks for your comment, I tried that as well. but still while printing its printing as black text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround: Generate an image on the fly. Image generation is quite simple in the server and relatively cheap too. Think captcha but with your colors, fonts, chosen text etc etc.

Should not be too big of a challenge to generate even from dynamic text. Animations will be harder, but possibly doable and if you are printing it anyway, derp!

Answer (score 0):

No. Websites cannot change browser settings.

That would be major security flaw if javascript on a website could change the users preferences in the browser.

*Imagine if websites could enable popups in the browser.*

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer as per the Nenotlep suggesion. here is my below code to solve my problem.

```
private void LoadBlackImage(string imageUrl, string firstName, string lastName, string Number, string Date)
        {
            Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(imageUrl));
            Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
            SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

            HtmlGenericControl dynImage = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
            dynImage.ID = "imgBlack";
            dynImage.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");


            //Smooth graphics is nice.
            graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            //Write your text.
            graphicImage.DrawString(firstName, new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular), drawBrush, new Point(50, 70));
            graphicImage.DrawString(lastName, new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular), drawBrush, new Point(50, 85));
            graphicImage.DrawString(Number, new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular), drawBrush, new Point(50, 100));
            graphicImage.DrawString(Date, new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular), drawBrush, new Point(50, 115));

            //Save the new image to the response output stream.
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bitMapImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            //lblGiftCardRightIO.Src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Data;
            dynImage.Attributes.Add("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Data);
            divControl.Controls.Add(dynImage);

            //Clean house.
            graphicImage.Dispose();
            bitMapImage.Dispose();
        }
```

Thank you all for your time and help

Many Thanks
Anna