# Why does the media attribute in the link element does not work for the print value?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Add your content here-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is screen.css:

```
body {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Here is print.css:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The screen looks good, the way it should, with the cyan background color. However, the print preview shows a white background color. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select an option 'Apply background color and images' in print settings of your browser.

Following link might be of help.[css media type print using background-color in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768717/css-media-type-print-using-background-color-in-chrome)

[image]