# print paginated table (simplePagination.js by flaviusmatis)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, pagination

```js
var search;

var searchdiv = $("#searchdiv");
var perPage = 3;
searchdiv.pagination({
  itemsOnPage: perPage,
  cssStyle: "light-theme",
  onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
    var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
    var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

    search.hide()
      .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
  }
});

function updateItems() {
  search = $(".geoname");
  searchdiv.pagination("updateItems", search.length);
  var page = Math.min(
    searchdiv.pagination("getCurrentPage"),
    searchdiv.pagination("getPagesCount")

  );

  searchdiv.pagination("selectPage", page);
}
updateItems();

var geo = {
  "geonames": [{
    "lng": -99.12766456604,
    "geonameId": 3530597,
    "countrycode": "MX",
    "name": "Mexiko-Stadt",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Mexico City",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_City",
    "lat": 19.428472427036,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 12294193,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": 116.397228240967,
    "geonameId": 1816670,
    "countrycode": "CN",
    "name": "Peking",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Beijing",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing",
    "lat": 39.9074977414405,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 11716620,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": 120.9822,
    "geonameId": 1701668,
    "countrycode": "PH",
    "name": "Manila",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Manila",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manila",
    "lat": 14.6042,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 10444527,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": 90.40743827819824,
    "geonameId": 1185241,
    "countrycode": "BD",
    "name": "Dhaka",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Dhaka",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhaka",
    "lat": 23.710395616597037,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 10356500,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": 126.9784,
    "geonameId": 1835848,
    "countrycode": "KR",
    "name": "Seoul",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Seoul",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seoul",
    "lat": 37.566,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 10349312,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": 106.84513092041016,
    "geonameId": 1642911,
    "countrycode": "ID",
    "name": "Jakarta",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Jakarta",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta",
    "lat": -6.214623197035775,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 8540121,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": 139.69171,
    "geonameId": 1850147,
    "countrycode": "JP",
    "name": "Tokyo",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Tokyo",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo",
    "lat": 35.6895,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 8336599,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": 121.531846,
    "geonameId": 1668341,
    "countrycode": "TW",
    "name": "Taipeh",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Taipei",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taipei",
    "lat": 25.047763,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 7871900,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": -74.08175468444824,
    "geonameId": 3688689,
    "countrycode": "CO",
    "name": "Bogotá",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Bogotá",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogot%C3%A1",
    "lat": 4.609705849789108,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 7674366,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }, {
    "lng": 114.157691001892,
    "geonameId": 1819729,
    "countrycode": "HK",
    "name": "Hong Kong",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "toponymName": "Hong Kong",
    "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
    "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong",
    "lat": 22.2855225817732,
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 7012738,
    "fcode": "PPLC"
  }]
}

geonames = geo.geonames;

var data = geonames;


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr class=geoname/>');
  if (data[i].geonameId) {
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].countrycode + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].lng + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].lat + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].population + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].geonameId + "</td>");

    tr.append("<td id=''>" + "<a class=geonameview  id=" + data[i].geonameId + " href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td>");

  } else {
    tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''></td>");

  }

  $("#geonames").append(tr);
}
updateItems();









function printpage() {
  window.print();
}
```

```css
@media print {
  .dontprint {
    display: none
  }
  body {
    display: block;
  }
}
body {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js/master/simplePagination.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js/master/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>



<table id="geonames" class="searchresult" border="1">
  <tr id="">
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Country Code
    </th>
    <th>
      Longitude
    </th>
    <th>
      Latitude
    </th>
    <th>
      Population
    </th>
    <th>
      ID
    </th>
    <th>
      Action
    </th>
  </tr>

</table>
<div id="searchdiv" class="dontprint"></div>
<button onclick="printpage()" class="dontprint" style="float: right">Print Preview</button>
```

Using

```
$('.printMe').click(function(){
     window.print();
});
```

I can print entire screen. In my screen i have a table which is paginated using the [flaviusmatis Simple Pagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/). So i have buttons in the table. I added

```
.dontprint{ 
    display : none
}
```

for elements that i dont need to print that includes the button in the pagination.

**If i have 50 pages that is so much click and waste of time.**

**Note**

I. As much as possible I don't want to use other than this pagination but if there are no option then I have no choice but use other pagination function with print function with them.

**Current Function**

Right now what I have to do is print them one by one. *I need to click to page 1 click print click page 2 click print and so on...*

**Aim Function**

Have a button that lets user print all the paginated pages on one click.

**Possible Approach**

On button click find button with active class(in the paginated pages) click print button (in code) then click on next button (in code) then click print (in code) and so until the last page. *still working on this one*

**Question**

1. Is there a way where I can just click one button and be able to print all the paginated pages.
2. If I have say 20 pages that will be at least 39 click and **I am not sure if it will cause the page to shut down**(if possible approach is done)

**Update**

I don't want to print all the pages into one. What I want is print the pages as it is. Meaning each page separately from other pages. *I hope I am making sense*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:*** I no longer recommend the iFrame approach. There are better alternatives like printing a new window or hiding/showing certain parts of the page when printing.

What you can do is add the table to an iframe and then print just that iframe.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gy40hd0/) because SO code snippet wouldn't allow me to print an iframe.

In the fiddle I've added a hidden iframe to the body called "print_frame" and then added a `<style>` tag to it and the `#geonames` table.

```
function printpage() {
  // display the hidden table rows
  var style = "<style>.geoname {display: table-row !important; }</style>";

  window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = style + $("#geonames")[0].outerHTML;
  window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
  window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}
```

If you want to use your stylesheet in the iframe be aware there are cross-domain issues.

**UPDATE**

To break the content into multiple pages you need to use the [page-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/) CSS property.

This unfortunately doesn't work on `<tr>` which don't have `display: block`. So in your function to generate the table rows I've added this code which adds a hidden row we'll break on and also makes a copy of the header row for each new page.

```
if ((i + 1) % perPage === 0) {
  $("#geonames").append("<tr class='pagebreak'></tr>")
  $("#geonames").append($("#headerRow").clone().addClass("headerCopy"));
}
```

CSS for the breaking rows

```
.pagebreak { display: block; page-break-after: always; }
```

However, because the table now extends down the entire page, you'll see the table's border down the entire page. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDxOO.png) (too tall to show here)

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gy40hd0/1/)

**UPDATE 2**

After some more testing by OP, it was found that breaking the page on table rows produced some strange results with extra whitespace at the top of the page.

Workaround was to create a new table for each page and then break on the table.

[Update Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zf5paqwd/3/)

Comment: i am sorry i think the question wasnt clear enough. I dont want to print the print in one print all together. what i want is in my example above page  1 have 3 entries print only 3 page 2 has 3 entries print only that and so on. I hope i am making sense now

Comment: @guradio I've updated my answer. I was unsure if you wanted the header to be displayed on each page but it is there if you want.

Comment: what could be a work around for the table border?i mean it would be odd seeing those line wont it?

Comment: @guradio You could get rid of the table border and only have the border on the row elements except the `.pagebreak` rows. Or you could create a new table for each page and break the page on those tables if you wanted borders on the tables and the rows.

Comment: that could be a solution thank you i really appreciate the idea and the very nice answer :) happy coding mate by the way i just learned the `page-break-after: always` from thank alot :)

Comment: @guradio Happy to help. Make sure to thoroughly test your project across multiple browsers. I remember the last time I did printing from a website it drove me mad trying to get every browser to print the same. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768717/css-media-type-print-using-background-color-in-chrome) helped a lot for Chrome.

Comment: i have one question i have problem when doing many record the page break fails see  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/zf5paqwd/1/). the 5th one breaks. in my code it breaks so much that the pages are messed up. also when i use .after() it is messed up. any idea why or how?

Comment: @guradio When you say it breaks what do you mean? Using Chrome, I can see some white space at the start of some pages starting from page 5. Is this what you mean? Where are you using .after()? How does it mess it up?

Comment: pls see the demo on some page it does not go to next page some pages breaks too much the top pages starts at bottom page

Comment: @guradio Which browser are you using?

Comment: im using chrome has it something to do with browser?mozilla has no print preview so i am using chorme

Comment: @guradio Let's talk in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/109290/discussion-between-jaydo-and-guradio?tab=general)

Comment: Mate i have a question i need clarification. I was able to properly adopt the answer to my code. Except for 1 instance. I've been trying to come up solutions for this for days that is why i decided to ask you. What if i wanted to add 2 more tr after the actual table. This is the scenario where i cant find the solution. The page break is not working if this is the scenario.

Comment: @guradio Can you clarify "add 2 more tr after the actual table"?

Comment: mate can you go to that chat i am there i dont want to spam in comment box thank you